# How to inject a collection of a service into a strategy implementing that same service?

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a service `IService` and an implementation `StrategyService` like that:

```cs
interface IService
{
    // interface declaration here
}

class StrategyService: IService
{
    IService[] services;

    StrategyService(params IService[] services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }

    // interface implementation here
}
```

Now let's say I have 2 implementations of `IService`: `Service1` & `Service2`. I want to tell Castle Windsor to take instances of `Service1` and `Service2` as parameters for the component `StrategyService`.

Here is my test:

```cs
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
container.Register(
    Component.For<IService>().Instance(new Service1()).Named("service1"),
    Component.For<IService>().Instance(new Service2()).Named("service2"),
    Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<StrategyService>());

var service = container.Resolve<IService>();
// `service` is of type `Service1`
```

How can I get an instance of `StrategyService` with `service1` and `service2` as parameters?

Comment: It seems that StrategyService is a special case of IService -- it is not semantically equal to IService. So I would either extract that purpose to another interface (IServiceManager) or simply just register StrategyService directly - i.e. not as implementation of IService. Then you can simply rely on the CollectionResolver to do its thing.

Comment: Although I agree that it "simplify" the registration process, I do not really agree to do that because, from the point of view of the consumer of `IService`, they should never be forced to know that there is a strategy or an intermediate service to serve as a strategy. I want them to resolve `IService` then consume `IService`, nothing more than that, it is not their concern and they should not know about the implementation details. (It may be a pipe dream, but let me dream of such a world )

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the declaration of the components like this:

```cs
container.Register(
    Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<StrategyService>(),
    Component.For<IService>().Instance(new Service1()).Named("service1"),
    Component.For<IService>().Instance(new Service2()).Named("service2"));
```

There is some magic here, has it seems to resolve the first component declared, but use only the two next ones excluding that first into the array to be injected.